# Why SSSD Service override_homedir triggers creation of home directory with wrong permissions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pam, umask, sssd

I have a vendor application installed in an Ubuntu Jammy server that relies on SSSD v2.6.3 configured for LDAP integration for the authentication and creation of the home directory of the user in the server.

In the sssd.conf configuration it is present:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version=2
reconnection_retries=3
services=nss,pam
domains=mydomain.com

[nss]
...

[pam]
...

[domain/mydomain.com]
... ldap configuration ...
override_homedir=/sfs/home/%u
```

When user is authenticated the home directory created has the following set of permissions:

```
$ ls -lhtar /sfs/home
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser mygroup 4.0K Jan  3 19:23 myuser
```

Unfortunately the permissions `drwxr-xr-x` give also access to others to navigate in their home directory.

At the beginning I thought this was controlled by the PAM modules, in particular, the `common-session` executing the `pam_mkhomedir.so` module, **however this is not the case!!!**, since commenting this module does not have any effect, and also the home directory is always completely empty, not following the home "skeleton" usually provided in the mkhomedir e.g. `session required pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/`.

I also noticed that the permissions `drwxr-xr-x` correspond to a umask 022 which is usually the default in the linux distributions, so I have modify to a 006 in `/etc/login.defs` and also add the umask 006 in `/etc/profile` to avoid the use of the 022 umask, however this attempt has been also in vain.

is there anyone out there that has had this issue?
How can you force the right umask when home directory creation is being triggered by the SSSD service?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the problem actually resided in the vendor application doing the authentication that did not trigger the PAM modules for the session, a modification on this vendor application's configuration allowed the authentication process to invoke the PAM session configuration we have set for creating the home directory.